# How to Explicitly specify the groups in Pandas groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a DataFrame containing customer purchase information.  I would like to `groupby` the `date` column to determine the total sales each day.  My problem is that there are some days with no purchases whatsoever.  I would like the groupby object to include those missing days as groups with the total sales equal to 0.  Is there a way to pass a list of the **values** of the `date` column to the `groupby` function?  MWE below

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...            'purchase_id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
...            'date' : ['1900-01-01', '1900-01-01', '1900-01-03', '1900-01-04'],
...            'cost' : [1.00, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75]
... })
```

This group by has the following result.

```
>>> df.groupby('date').agg({'cost':'sum'})

date           cost
'1900-01-01'   1.25
'1900-01-03'   0.50
'1900-01-04'   0.75
```

What command can I execute to obtain the following result instead?  (Obviously I will have to pass the dates I am expecting to see as an argument, which is fine.)

```
date           cost
'1900-01-01'   1.25
'1900-01-02'   0.00
'1900-01-03'   0.50
'1900-01-04'   0.75
```

Comment: So do you want to pass the dates that should be displayed, or to display all dates from start to finish with the interval of 1 day?

Comment: @VladimirFokow I would expect to have to pass in all the dates from first to finish with increments of 1 as an argument. Should be easy enough to write code to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reindex`:

```
df.groupby('date').agg({'cost':'sum'}).reindex(your_new_date_list)
```

However, I'd recommend you convert your data to `datetime` type, then you can use `resample`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df.resample('d', on='date')['cost'].sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
        date  cost
0 1900-01-01  1.25
1 1900-01-02  0.00
2 1900-01-03  0.50
3 1900-01-04  0.75
```